# How do a concatenate successful a variable in a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I read a lot of topics, but nothing working for me.

The query doesn't like php variable in FROM .

I tried:

```
$f="201406"; 
$atemp="zzz_reservationservicedocumentgenerateddocs_"; 
echo $a_temp.=$f;
```

And i put `{$a_temp}` in SQL `{$a_temp}` and working... but it's not what i want...
When i'm using variable in different cases doesn't work.

For example:

```
for($get_months=date("Ym");$get_months>=201401;$get_months--)
 {         
               echo $get_months;
 }
```

If I tried to add $get_months in SQL query for example:

```
FROM zzz_reservationservicedocumentgenerateddocs_$get_months
```

If I tried to declare variable:

```
$get_months="201406";
```

It works!

The query seems like

```
"SELECT * FROM zzz_reservationservicedocumentgenerateddocs_$get_months"
```

Comment: Can you show the whole code, not just the little bits? What you've shown should work, so it must have something to do with how you've put everything together. I suspect it's a variable scope problem, but can't tell from what you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question.. but i'll show the basics of concatenation:

```
$String_1 = "This is one string";
$String_2 = " This is another string"; 
  echo $String_1.$String_2;
```

This will output:

> This is one string This is another string

If using in a foreach loop:

```
$Array = array(1,2,3,4,5);
foreach ($Array AS $Value){
   echo "Current Number :".$Value;
}
```

The output will be:

> Current Number:1
>
> Current Number:2
>
> Current Number:3
>
> Current Number:4
>
> Current Number:5

and a normal flaw people normally encounter:

```
foreach ($Array AS $Value){
 //Do manipulations
}
echo "Current Number: ".$Value;
```

You will get

> Current Number: 5

as the last iteration is stored